# Build Code First Migrations from class internal to a Nuget package

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

We are looking to add feature toggles to several applications.  We will store the toggles in each application's database.

Our plan is to build a FeatureToggle NuGet package.  Ideally, this package would expose only a FeatureToggle class.  The other classes (the DbContext, the EF models, etc.) would all be internal to the package.

The problem, of course, is that the migrations won't compile because they refer to classes internal to the NuGet package.

Is it possible to build and execute CodeFirst migrations based on an internal class?

Is there a common/standard technique for designing NuGet packages that add tables to existing databases.

Answer (score 1):

No, `internal` classes can only be referenced from the same assembly they are defined in.

I don't know about a common/standard way of achieving this, but I do know I've used nuget packages that run sql scripts on initialization to add their own required tables. If your consuming application doesn't need to directly access any of these internal classes or tables I would suggest looking into that method.

For reference, the library I've used which does this is [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) - see github source: [Hangfire/SqlServerObjectsInstaller.cs](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/SqlServerObjectsInstaller.cs) which runs the appropriate [install.sql](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/Install.sql) script to add everything without needing the end user to create migrations etc.